# How to retrieve more than 100 messages from the history of a PubNub channel?

Tags: history, pubnub

The page about the [PubNub History API](http://www.pubnub.com/docs/javascript/overview/storage-playback.html#history) states that

> The history() function returns a list of up to 100 messages, the start
>   time token and the ending time token.

Is there a way to retrieve more than the 100 messages?

I'm currently not a paying customer of PubNub.

Comment: What language are you programming in?

Comment: There are several options.  Do you want a full dump of history?  Or do you only want snapshots over the past 24 hours?

Comment: I went ahead and gave you both answers in JavaScript.

Comment: @PubNub, thank you a lot for the comprehensive answer! This is what I needed.

Comment: You are welcome indeed!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## PubNub Load History More than 100 Messages

Sometimes you want to slice back in time over a linear stream of data.  And often you'll want to do this at different levels of granularity.  That is why PubNub Storage and Playback APIs provide maximum level of flexibility.  However sometimes it ends up being a bit tricky to load data with the preferred result set.

[image: PubNub Real-Time Network Storage and Playback API]

> **[PubNub Real-Time Network Storage and Playback](http://www.pubnub.com/how-it-works/storage-and-playback/)**

There are several considerations you may be seeking when loading transaction history over timelines that can potentially span millions of message in the transaction set.  There are some great options available to you and we will cover two of them right now.  The examples will be coded in JavaScript.  The first example loads a summary of the data by grabbing the snapshots for the beginning of each hour for the past 24 hours.  The second example shows you how to load all transactions in full detail and maximum granularity.

> *All Reference Files can be found on this [**GIST: Loading History from PubNub Mt.Gox Trades**](https://gist.github.com/stephenlb/8312648)*

### Example PubNub Mt.Gox History JavaScript Usage

```
<script src="https://cdn.pubnub.com/pubnub.min.js"></script>
<script src="mtgox-history.js"></script>
<script>(function(){

// LOAD HOURLY SUMMARY
MTGOX.history.hourly({
    channel : 'd5f06780-30a8-4a48-a2f8-7ed181b4a13f',
    data    : function(response) { console.log(JSON.stringify(response)) },
    error   : function()         { console.log("NETWORK ERROR")  } 
});

// LOAD ALL WITH LIMITER OPTION
MTGOX.history.full({
    limit   : 500, // SET LIMIT AS HIGH AS NEEDED TO LOAD MORE!
    channel : 'd5f06780-30a8-4a48-a2f8-7ed181b4a13f',
    data    : function(messages) { console.log(messages)        },
    error   : function(e)        { console.log("NETWORK ERROR") }
});

})();</script>
```

> **NOTE:** Running `MTGOX.history.hourly()` method will generate a list of snapshots per hour over the last 24 hours.
>
> **NOTE:** Running `MTGOX.history.full()` method will generate maximum resolution detail with a lot of data.  You can get a full dump or partial dump as needed; and you should increase the `limit` parameter in order to grab more data points.

This following JavaScript file will provide you the `MTGOX` interface.

### PubNub Mt.Gox History JavaScript Loader

```
//
// mtgox-history.js
//

(function(){

// -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
// INITIALIZE PUBNUB
// -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
var pubnub = PUBNUB.init({
    subscribe_key : 'sub-c-50d56e1e-2fd9-11e3-a041-02ee2ddab7fe'
});

// -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
// MTGOX HISTORY INTERFACE
// -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
window.MTGOX = {
    history : {
        hourly : hourly,
        full   : full
    }
};

// -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
// GET ALL DATA FOREVER (WITH LIMIT OF COURSE)
// -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-

/*
MTGOX.history.full({
    limit   : 1000,
    channel : 'd5f06780-30a8-4a48-a2f8-7ed181b4a13f',
    data    : function(messages) { console.log(messages)        },
    error   : function(e)        { console.log("NETWORK ERROR") }
});
*/

function full(args) {
    var chan     = args['channel'] ||'d5f06780-30a8-4a48-a2f8-7ed181b4a13f'
    ,   callback = args['data']   || function(){}
    ,   error    = args['error']  || function(){}
    ,   limit    = +args['limit'] || 5000
    ,   start    = 0
    ,   count    = 100
    ,   history  = []
    ,   params   = {
            channel  : chan,
            count    : count,
            callback : function(messages) {
                var msgs = messages[0];
                start = messages[1];
                params.start = start;
                PUBNUB.each( msgs.reverse(), function(m) {history.push(m)} );

                if (history.length >= limit) return callback(history);
                if (msgs.length < count)     return callback(history);

                count = 100;
                add_messages();
            },
            error : function(e) {
                callback(history);
                error(history);
            }
        };

    add_messages();
    function add_messages() { pubnub.history(params) }
}

// -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
// GET 24 HOURS IN HOURLY INCREMENTS
// -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-

/*
MTGOX.history.hourly({
    channel : 'd5f06780-30a8-4a48-a2f8-7ed181b4a13f',
    data    : function(response) { console.log(response) },
    error   : function()         { console.log('ERROR')  } 
});
*/

function hourly(setup) {
    var limit = 24;
    var count = 0;
    var chan  = setup['channel'] ||'d5f06780-30a8-4a48-a2f8-7ed181b4a13f';
    var cb    = setup['data']    || function(){};
    var eb    = setup['error']   || function(){};
    var now   = new Date();

    now.setUTCHours(0);
    now.setUTCMinutes(0);
    now.setUTCSeconds(0);
    now.setUTCMilliseconds(0);

    var utc_now = now.getTime();
    var vectors = [];

    PUBNUB.each( (new Array(limit)).join(',').split(','), function( _, d ) {
        var day = utc_now - 3600000 * d;
        pubnub.history({
            limit    : 1,
            channel  : chan,
            start    : day * 10000,
            error    : function() { count++; eb(); },
            callback : function(messages) {
                // DONE?
                if (++count == limit) return cb(vectors);

                // ADD TIME SLICES
                var res = +(((messages[0][0]||{}).ticker||{}).avg||{}).value;
                res && vectors.push([ new Date(day).getUTCHours(), res ]);

                // KEEP IT SORTED
                vectors.sort(function(a,b){ return a[0] > b[0] && -1 || 1 });
            }
        })
    } );
}

})();
```

### Mt.Gox PubNub Channel Listing for Tickers, Depth and Trades

The following is a list of channels provided by Mt.Gox data feed options you can use in the history `channel` parameter field.

```
{
"TICKER.ltcgbp": "0102A446-E4D4-4082-8E83-CC02822F9172",
"TICKER.ltccny": "0290378C-E3D7-4836-8CB1-2BFAE20CC492",
"DEPTH.btchkd": "049F65DC-3AF3-4FFD-85A5-AAC102B2A579",
"DEPTH.btceur": "057BDC6B-9F9C-44E4-BC1A-363E4443CE87",
"TICKER.nmcaud": "08C65460-CBD9-492E-8473-8507DFA66AE6",
"TICKER.btceur": "0BB6DA8B-F6C6-4ECF-8F0D-A544AD948C15",
"DEPTH.btckrw": "0C84BDA7-E613-4B19-AE2A-6D26412C9F70",
"DEPTH.btccny": "0D1ECAD8-E20F-459E-8BED-0BDCF927820F",
"TICKER.btccad": "10720792-084D-45BA-92E3-CF44D9477775",
"DEPTH.btcchf": "113FEC5F-294D-4929-86EB-8CA4C3FD1BED",
"TICKER.ltcnok": "13616AE8-9268-4A43-BDF7-6B8D1AC814A2",
"TICKER.ltcusd": "1366A9F3-92EB-4C6C-9CCC-492A959ECA94",
"TICKER.btcbtc": "13EDFF67-CFA0-4D99-AA76-52BD15D6A058",
"TICKER.ltccad": "18B55737-3F5C-4583-AF63-6EB3951EAD72",
"TICKER.nmccny": "249FDEFD-C6EB-4802-9F54-064BC83908AA",
"DEPTH.btcusd": "24E67E0D-1CAD-4CC0-9E7A-F8523EF460FE",
"TICKER.btcchf": "2644C164-3DB7-4475-8B45-C7042EFE3413",
"DEPTH.btcaud": "296EE352-DD5D-46F3-9BEA-5E39DEDE2005",
"TICKER.btcczk": "2A968B7F-6638-40BA-95E7-7284B3196D52",
"TICKER.btcsgd": "2CB73ED1-07F4-45E0-8918-BCBFDA658912",
"TICKER.nmcjpy": "314E2B7A-A9FA-4249-BC46-B7F662ECBC3A",
"TICKER.btcnmc": "36189B8C-CFFA-40D2-B205-FB71420387AE",
"DEPTH.btcinr": "414FDB18-8F70-471C-A9DF-B3C2740727EA",
"DEPTH.btcsgd": "41E5C243-3D44-4FAD-B690-F39E1DBB86A8",
"TICKER.btcltc": "48B6886F-49C0-4614-B647-BA5369B449A9",
"TICKER.ltceur": "491BC9BB-7CD8-4719-A9E8-16DAD802FFAC",
"TICKER.btcinr": "55E5FEB8-FEA5-416B-88FA-40211541DECA",
"TICKER.ltcjpy": "5AD8E40F-6DF3-489F-9CF1-AF28426A50CF",
"DEPTH.btccad": "5B234CC3-A7C1-47CE-854F-27AEE4CDBDA5",
"TICKER.btcnzd": "5DDD27CA-2466-4D1A-8961-615DEDB68BF1",
"DEPTH.btcgbp": "60C3AF1B-5D40-4D0E-B9FC-CCAB433D2E9C",
"DEPTH.btcnok": "66DA7FB4-6B0C-4A10-9CB7-E2944E046EB5",
"DEPTH.btcthb": "67879668-532F-41F9-8EB0-55E7593A5AB8",
"TICKER.btcsek": "6CAF1244-655B-460F-BEAF-5C56D1F4BEA7",
"TICKER.btcnok": "7532E866-3A03-4514-A4B1-6F86E3A8DC11",
"TICKER.btcgbp": "7B842B7D-D1F9-46FA-A49C-C12F1AD5A533",
"TRADE.LAG": "85174711-BE64-4DE1-B783-0628995D7914",
"DEPTH.btcsek": "8F1FEFAA-7C55-4420-ADA0-4DE15C1C38F3",
"DEPTH.btcdkk": "9219ABB0-B50C-4007-B4D2-51D1711AB19C",
"DEPTH.btcjpy": "94483E07-D797-4DD4-BC72-DC98F1FD39E3",
"TICKER.nmcusd": "9AAEFD15-D101-49F3-A2FD-6B63B85B6BED",
"TICKER.ltcaud": "A046600A-A06C-4EBF-9FFB-BDC8157227E8",
"TICKER.btcjpy": "A39AE532-6A3C-4835-AF8C-DDA54CB4874E",
"DEPTH.btcczk": "A7A970CF-4F6C-4D85-A74E-AC0979049B87",
"TICKER.ltcdkk": "B10A706E-E8C7-4EA8-9148-669F86930B36",
"TICKER.btcpln": "B4A02CB3-2E2D-4A88-AEEA-3C66CB604D01",
"TEST": "BAD99F24-FA8B-4938-BFDF-0C1831FC6665",
"TICKER.btcrub": "BD04F720-3C70-4DCE-AE71-2422AB862C65",
"TICKER.nmcgbp": "BF5126BA-5187-456F-8AE6-963678D0607F",
"TICKER.btckrw": "BF85048D-4DB9-4DBE-9CA3-5B83A1A4186E",
"TICKER.btccny": "C251EC35-56F9-40AB-A4F6-13325C349DE4",
"DEPTH.btcnzd": "CEDF8730-BCE6-4278-B6FE-9BEE42930E95",
"TICKER.btchkd": "D3AE78DD-01DD-4074-88A7-B8AA03CD28DD",
"TICKER.btcthb": "D58E3B69-9560-4B9E-8C58-B5C0F3FDA5E1",
"TICKER.btcusd": "D5F06780-30A8-4A48-A2F8-7ED181B4A13F",
"DEPTH.btcrub": "D6412CA0-B686-464C-891A-D1BA3943F3C6",
"TICKER.nmceur": "D8512D04-F262-4A14-82F2-8E5C96C15E68",
"TRADE.btc": "DBF1DEE9-4F2E-4A08-8CB7-748919A71B21",
"TICKER.nmccad": "DC28033E-7506-484C-905D-1C811A613323",
"DEPTH.btcpln": "E4FF055A-F8BF-407E-AF76-676CAD319A21",
"TICKER.btcdkk": "E5CE0604-574A-4059-9493-80AF46C776B3",
"TICKER.btcaud": "EB6AAA11-99D0-4F64-9E8C-1140872A423D"
}
```

Comment: I was trying to do this in Java. With your javascript exampe I found my problem. I had to convert the millis time into 10th of microseconds time: long pubnubTime = standardJavaMillisTime * 10000. It might save some time for Java developers if you include this info in the docs on the `Pubnub.history(final String channel, long start, long end, int count, boolean reverse, final Callback callback)` method.

Comment: Good find Daniel, I've added this in our list of items to do.

Answer (score 1):

See https://help.pubnub.com/entries/24113341-How-do-I-Page-Through-Stored-Messages-
Contact PubNub support (help@...) if further assistance is needed

Answer (score 0):

The below Java class can be used to easily retrieve and process long time ranges of history messages in an advanced for loop of this form:

```
PubnubHistoryExcerpt history = new PubnubHistoryExcerpt(pubnub, channel, start, end);
for (Object message : history) {
    // do something with the message object
}
```

The messages are retrieved on the fly, so no memory problem occurs.

Below is the complete code. You can find a fully runnable usage example in the `main()` method inside of the class.

I haven't yet tested this class extensively. Enhancements are welcome.

```
/*
 * PubnubHistoryExcerpt.java
 * 
 * This file is distributed under the FreeBSD License:
 * 
 * Copyright (c) 2014, Daniel S. (http://stackoverflow.com/users/1838726/daniel-s)
 * All rights reserved.
 * 
 * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
 * modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are met: 
 * 
 * 1. Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice, this
 *    list of conditions and the following disclaimer. 
 * 2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice,
 *    this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation
 *    and/or other materials provided with the distribution. 
 * 
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS" AND
 * ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED
 * WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE
 * DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT OWNER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR
 * ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES
 * (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES;
 * LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND
 * ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT
 * (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS
 * SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
 * 
 * The views and conclusions contained in the software and documentation are those
 * of the authors and should not be interpreted as representing official policies, 
 * either expressed or implied, of the FreeBSD Project.
 */

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.pubnub.api.Callback;
import com.pubnub.api.Pubnub;
import com.pubnub.api.PubnubError;

/**
 * You can use this class to iterate over historical PubNub messages. The messages are retrieved transparently while you
 * iterate over the history excerpt. This class and the returned iterators are thread-safe.
 * 
 * See {@link #main(String[])} for a usage example.
 */
public class PubnubHistoryExcerpt implements Iterable<Object> {

    /**
     * This main method contains a usage example for this class. It downloads last 3 hour's messages of the MtGox BTC/USD ticker
     * channel from PubNub and outputs the timestamp and USD value which are found in the messages.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException {
        String PUBNUB_SUBSCRIBE_KEY_MTGOX = "sub-c-50d56e1e-2fd9-11e3-a041-02ee2ddab7fe";
        String PUBNUB_CHANNEL_MTGOX_TICKER_BTCUSD = "d5f06780-30a8-4a48-a2f8-7ed181b4a13f";

        Pubnub pubnub = new Pubnub(null, PUBNUB_SUBSCRIBE_KEY_MTGOX);

        long ONE_HOUR_IN_MILLIS = 60 * 60 * 1000;

        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long start = end - 3 * ONE_HOUR_IN_MILLIS;

        // convert from milliseconds as time unit (10^-3 seconds) to
        // pubnub's better-than-microsecond precision time units (10^-7 seconds)
        start *= 10000;
        end *= 10000;

        PubnubHistoryExcerpt history = new PubnubHistoryExcerpt(pubnub, PUBNUB_CHANNEL_MTGOX_TICKER_BTCUSD, start, end);

        DefaultDateFormat dateFormat = DefaultDateFormat.create();

        for (Object message : history) {
            JSONObject messageJson = (JSONObject) message;

            JSONObject ticker = messageJson.getJSONObject("ticker");
            long instant = ticker.getLong("now");
            BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal(ticker.getJSONObject("last_local").getString("value"));

            instant /= 1000; // convert from microseconds to milliseconds

            System.out.println(dateFormat.format(instant) + ": " + value);
        }

        System.exit(0);
    }

    /**
     * This is the maximum number of messages to fetch in one batch. If you fetch many messages, higher numbers improve
     * performance. Setting this to a value higher than 100 doesn't have an effect, because Pubnub currently doesn't
     * support fetching more than this many messages at once.
     */
    private static final int BATCH_SIZE = 100;

    private final Pubnub pubnub;

    private final String channel;

    private final long start;

    private final long end;

    /**
     * Constructs a new excerpt over which you can iterate. Insances represent an excerpt. No retrieval operations are
     * started unless you call iterator().next() for the first time.
     * 
     * @param pubnub
     *            The Pubnub connection to use for retrieving messages.
     * @param channel
     *            The channel for which to retrieve historical messages.
     * @param start
     *            The beginning of the time interval for which to retrieve messages, in pubnub's time units (10^-7
     *            seconds, so milliseconds * 10000) since 1970-01-01 00:00:00).
     * @param end
     *            The end of the time interval for which to retrieve messages, in pubnub's time units (10^-7 seconds, so
     *            milliseconds * 10000) since 1970-01-01 00:00:00).
     */
    private PubnubHistoryExcerpt(Pubnub pubnub, String channel, long start, long end) {
        this.pubnub = pubnub;
        this.channel = channel;
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
    }

    public Iterator<Object> iterator() {
        return new Iter();
    }

    private class Iter implements Iterator<Object> {

        /**
         * This list is used as a fifo buffer for messages retrieves through this iterator. It also acts as the main
         * synchronization lock for synchronizing access between threads accessing this class as an iterator and threads
         * calling back from the Pubnub API.
         */
        private LinkedList<Object> buffer = new LinkedList<Object>();

        /**
         * This field stores the end of the time range of the previous batch retrieval, in Pubnub time units (10th of a
         * microsecond, so milliseconds*10000). For the following batch retrieval, this is used as the start time for
         * retrieving the following messages.
         */
        private long prevBatchTimeRangeEnd = PubnubHistoryExcerpt.this.start;

        /**
         * Retrieval of messages is handled asynchronously. That means that exceptions which are thrown during retrieval
         * can't automatically be propagated through to the code which invokes <code>next()</code> or
         * <code>hasNext()</code> . Therefor, such an exception is stored temporarily in this field and then re-thrown
         * from within <code>next()</code> or <code>hasNext()</code>.
         */
        private Exception caughtDuringRetrieval = null;

        /**
         * This object is used to wait on and to notify about updates of the buffer.
         */
        private Object notifier = new Object();

        /**
         * Because of spurious wakeups that can happen during wait(), this field is necessary to tell the waiting thread
         * if retrieval is still running.
         */
        private boolean retrieving = false;

        /**
         * The callback object to use for retrieving messages. This is stored in a field here for re-use. This is a
         * compromise between performance and low memory footprint, slightly in favor of performance.
         */
        private InternalCallback internalCallback = new InternalCallback();

        private void retrieveNextBatch() {
            synchronized (notifier) {
                this.retrieving = true;

                // String startStr = DefaultDateFormat.create().format(prevBatchTimeRangeEnd / 10000);
                // String endStr = DefaultDateFormat.create().format(end / 10000);
                // System.out.println("fetching from " + startStr + " till " + endStr);

                if (Iter.this.prevBatchTimeRangeEnd < PubnubHistoryExcerpt.this.end) {
                    PubnubHistoryExcerpt.this.pubnub.history( //
                            PubnubHistoryExcerpt.this.channel, //
                            Iter.this.prevBatchTimeRangeEnd, //
                            PubnubHistoryExcerpt.this.end, //
                            BATCH_SIZE, //
                            false, //
                            Iter.this.internalCallback //
                            );

                    waitUntilNextBatchRetrievalFinished();
                }
            }
        }

        private void waitUntilNextBatchRetrievalFinished() {
            while (this.retrieving) {
                try {
                    this.notifier.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        private class InternalCallback extends Callback {

            @Override
            public void successCallback(String channel, Object message) {
                synchronized (Iter.this.notifier) {
                    try {
                        processSuccessCallback(channel, message);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Iter.this.caughtDuringRetrieval = e;
                    } finally {
                        Iter.this.retrieving = false;
                        Iter.this.notifier.notifyAll();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void errorCallback(String channel, PubnubError error) {
                Iter.this.caughtDuringRetrieval = new Exception("" + //
                        error.getClass().getName() + ": " + //
                        error.getErrorString() + //
                        " (code=" + error.errorCode + "; extendedCode=" + error.errorCodeExtended + ")");

                Iter.this.caughtDuringRetrieval.fillInStackTrace();
            }

        }

        private void processSuccessCallback(String channel, Object message) throws JSONException {
            if (message == null)
                throw new NullPointerException("retrieved message is null");

            if (!(message instanceof JSONArray))
                throw new RuntimeException("retrieved message is not a " + JSONArray.class.getName());

            JSONArray historyMessage = (JSONArray) message;

            // System.out.println(historyMessage.toString(2));

            JSONArray messageList = extractMessageList(historyMessage);

            long batchTimeRangeEnd = extractBatchTimeRangeEnd(historyMessage);
            if (batchTimeRangeEnd > 0)
                Iter.this.prevBatchTimeRangeEnd = batchTimeRangeEnd;
            else
                Iter.this.prevBatchTimeRangeEnd = end;

            processMessageList(messageList);
        }

        private void processMessageList(JSONArray messageList) {
            int i = 0;

            for (; i < messageList.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject message;

                try {
                    message = messageList.getJSONObject(i);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    String str;
                    try {
                        str = messageList.toString(2);
                    } catch (JSONException secondaryE) {
                        str = "(couldn't convert messageList to String because of " + secondaryE.toString() + ")";
                    }
                    throw new RuntimeException("couldn't extract message at index " + i + " from messageList (messageList:\n" + str
                            + "\n(end of messageList)\n)", e);
                }

                Iter.this.buffer.add(message);
            }
        }

        private long extractBatchTimeRangeEnd(JSONArray historyMessage) {
            long batchTimeRangeEnd;
            try {
                batchTimeRangeEnd = historyMessage.getLong(2);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                String str = safeConvertHistoryMessageToString(historyMessage);
                throw new RuntimeException("could not extract element 2 (batchTimeRangeEnd) of retrieved historyMessage (historyMessage:\n" + str
                        + "\n(end of historyMessage)\n)", e);
            }
            return batchTimeRangeEnd;
        }

        private String safeConvertHistoryMessageToString(JSONArray historyMessage) {
            String str;
            try {
                str = historyMessage.toString(2);
            } catch (JSONException secondaryE) {
                str = "(couldn't convert historyMessage to String because of " + secondaryE.toString() + ")";
            }
            return str;
        }

        private JSONArray extractMessageList(JSONArray historyMessage) {
            JSONArray messageArJson;
            try {
                messageArJson = historyMessage.getJSONArray(0);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                String str = safeConvertHistoryMessageToString(historyMessage);
                throw new RuntimeException("could not extract element 0 (messageList) of retrieved historyMessage (historyMessage:\n" + str
                        + "\n(end of historyMessage)\n)", e);
            }
            return messageArJson;
        }

        public boolean hasNext() {
            synchronized (Iter.this.buffer) {
                ensureNotInExceptionState();

                if (Iter.this.buffer.isEmpty())
                    retrieveNextBatch();

                return !Iter.this.buffer.isEmpty();
            }
        }

        public Object next() {
            synchronized (Iter.this.buffer) {
                if (!hasNext()) {
                    throw new NoSuchElementException("there are no more elements in this iterator");
                }

                Object result = Iter.this.buffer.removeFirst();

                return result;
            }
        }

        private void ensureNotInExceptionState() {
            if (caughtDuringRetrieval != null) {
                throw new RuntimeException("an exception was caught already by a previous attempt to access this iterator", caughtDuringRetrieval);
            }
        }

        public void remove() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException(getClass().getName() + " doesn't support remove()");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't errorCallback also `notifier.notifyAll()` in order to release other thread that are waiting on `notifier`?