# Pubnub History messages limitation more than hundred

Tags: javascript, android, pubnub

I am working on pubnub history and successfully getting 100 messages either of Newest, oldest or time format. I just want to get more than 100 messages history because the method given in Android Api is giving only 100 messages. How can I implement this pubnub history mechanism?

Comment: I have followed this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20976433/how-to-retrieve-more-than-100-messages-from-the-history-of-a-pubnub-channel but it is not helping me.

Answer (score 2):

To get the next COUNT number of messages, take the "end" timetoken returned, and use it as your next "start" parameter to your next call:

https://www.pubnub.com/docs/javascript/tutorial/storage-playback.html#_step_9_paging_through_messages